# How to implement the penalty in loan

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, I'm creating a loan API.

Can someone suggest how I implement the penalty function?

This is how the penalty works.

If the loan is not fully paid by 3 months, the remaining balance will be penalized by 1%, and then by another 1 month, if not fully paid, the remaining balance will be penalized by 1% again.

For example, if I loan 50,000 on 8-23-2022, I will be penalized 1% of the remaining balance on 11-23-2022 and then by next month, 12-23-2022, if not fully paid, penalized again of 1%.

this is my model for loan:

```
class Loan(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     loan_amount = models.IntegerField()
     date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and this is model for payments

```
class LoanPayment(models.Model):
     loan = models.ForeignKey(Loan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     payment_amount = models.IntegerField()
     date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and where are you stuck ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i try to use the apscheduler i add a new model called Penalty and then i schedule a function check if penalty if true i add data to Penalty model. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Where are your views? What have you implemented until now? 
And when do you want the penalty to be applied?

Answer (score 0):

You should first attack this problem through math calculation. Theoretically you can compute the total balance on arbitrary date given loan and all payments, and here is how.

If I took a loan ($50000 @8-23-2022) and never pay it, the total balance at date date_n is:

```
balance = 50000 * 1.01 ^ nom
```

where nom is number of months after 11-23-2022, and can be determined by:

```
nom = round_up( (date_n - 11-23-2022) / 30 )
```

(assume 1 month is 30 days, and nom is non-negative)

Now considering any payment on date_i with amount_i. Apart from reducing the total balance by amount_i, it also reduces the up coming penalty in a similar manner as loan. E.g. if I made a payment ($10000 @9-23-2022), it reduces the total penalty by $10000 * 1% = $100 on 11-23-2022, and another ($10000 + $100) * 1% = $101 on 12-23-2022. So the total balance on 12-24-2022 should be:

```
50000 * 1.01 ^ 2 - 10000 * 1.01 ^ 2 = 40804
```

In general, for a payment made on date_i with amount_i, at date_n, its contribution to total balance is:

```
contrib_i = -amount_i * 1.01 ^ nom_i
```

Here nom_i (number of months) is a little tricky. Intuitively, it is number of months after ***first penalty date***  after date_i:

```
first_penalty_date = round_up( (date_i - 11-23-2022) / 30 ) * 30 + 11-23-2022
```

and nom_i should be:

```
nom_i = round_up( (date_n - first_penalty_date) / 30 )
```

If we put it together and look into the equation, we find it essentially represents the total number of months, minus number of penalty months skipped by the payment:

```
nom_i = nom - round_up( (date_i - 11-23-2022) / 30 )
```

(this maybe sounds even more complicate, but it simplifies coding)

Then the total balance:

```
balance = loan_amount * 1.01 ^ nom - sum( amount_i * 1.01 ^ nom_i ) over payments
```

Above is the idea how you can implement the penalty function. If you need further help on how to achieve it in Django, leave a comment.